# Diazo theme not applied when activating RAM Cache in plone.app.caching in ZEO website

Tags: caching, plone, diazo

I've got a Plone 4.1.5 in ZEO, and when I activate RAM Cache in Plone Caching, the diazo theme is no longer applied.

I have checked the logs, there is nothing.

I'm running plone.app.theming-1.0b8 & plone.app.caching-1.0.3

Comment: For me the source of the problem was enabling gzip compression.  Disabled that and everything went smoothly.

Comment: I have gzip already activated, and no problem. The problem came when I enable RAM Cache...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be similar to that bug:
https://dev.plone.org/ticket/12038

Comment: Updating plone.app.theming & plone.app.caching to a newer version resolved my problem.